# Function to add rows to a dataTable in jquery gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my Jquery dataTable, `row.add` is not working and throws an error saying the add function is undefined. The error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthar/6q8zdgcf/6/)

**html**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<button id="addRow">Add new row</button>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var counter = 1;
    var prntTable = $('#example').dataTable( {  
       "aoColumns" : [ 
           {"bSearchable" : false}, 
           {"bSearchable" : true}, 
           {"bSearchable" : true}
        ],                                          
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
    } );

    $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        prntTable.row.add( [
            counter +'.1',
            counter +'.2',
            counter +'.3'
        ] ).draw();

        counter++;
    } ); 

    $('#addRow').click();
} );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
       prntTable.row.add( [
            counter +'.1',
            counter +'.2',
            counter +'.3'
        ] ).draw();

        counter++;
    } );
```

In this code the `prntTable` is undefined.Either define it as a global variable or redefine it in the click function

Add the

```
var prntTable = $('#example').DataTable();
```

after the click function

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/428fno3q/)

Comment: i got error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: the fiddle works fine for me..Have you checked it..??

Comment: the undefined error is caused due to the above reason.Do clear your browser cache before checkin it mate.. :)

Comment: I think it is important to note that Ankur's answer below helps clarify the answer.  Even though Outlooker says to use DataTable, I glossed over the capital D the first time I read it. table.row.add() will not work if you are using dataTable.  you must use DataTable.  This fixed the problem I was having and I verified it in the fiddle from Outlooker.

Answer (score 18):

**Instead of:**

```
var prntTable = $("#example").dataTable();
```

**Try:**

```
var prntTable = $("#example").DataTable();
```

It looks like the old datatables API `dataTable()` does not support the function you are calling. Use the new API with: `DataTable()`. Read here for more info: [Datatable API](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-02-04#API)

Comment: This solved my problem. The old dataTable() should not even exist.

Answer (score 2):

try to use fnAddData it works for me

```
table.fnAddData(['1','1','2','3','4']);
```

Comment: table.fnAddData(['1','1','2','3','4']);
i am getting error table.fnAddData is not a function